# подогнать кнопку (button) под размер картинки (ImageView) Android Studio

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

Здравствуйте! Я новичек в Android разработке, столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть динамическая страница(В зависимости от позиции в лист вью контент меняется динамически, но шаблон один и тот же) Картинка ImageView соотвественно разного размера в зависимости от позиции.

Идет картинка под ней кнопка. Нужно ширину кнопки выровнять под ширину картинки.

Вообщем буду рад любым советам! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего будет устанавливать размер кнопки после того, как будет известен размер изображения:

```
imageView.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           button.setWidth(imageView.getWidth());
       }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Для `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Для `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```